# How to convert Numpy index to coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I wanted to customize **getitem** for my array class. But I don't know how to convert the indices to coordinates. For example, for an array with shape (2,2,2), if one requests A[...,1], I'd like to get the coordinates as [[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]. Are there any functions in Numpy that can achieve this? Thanks.

To be more specific, I'm implementing a block sparse tensor class, where the blocks are related by symmetry. In other words, only the symmetry unique blocks are stored in memory or on disk, and all the other blocks can be obtained by performing either unitary transformations or transpositions of the stored blocks. In addition, I want the API to be the same as the Numpy ndarray. So when the user requests the blocks of the tensor using say Numpy advanced indexing, I need to know exactly which blocks are requested so that I can apply the corresponding transformations to compute and return those blocks.

Comment: It's unclear what you need exactly. Are you looking for a function that would actually return a collection of written out indices that match an indexing that includes an ellipsis? Or are you just looking to index those actual array elements? Because `numpy` supports the use of the ellipsis in indexing by default. What do you need the expanded indices for? This has the whiff of an XY problem?

Comment: You can explore custom index by reading the `np.lib.index_tricks.py` file.  But be careful when trying to change the indexing for `np.ndarray` or a subclass of that.  `numpy` indexing quite complex.  For a start I'd stick with writing functions that do what you want.  Using indexing notation can wait until you have a better understanding of python and numpy.

Comment: thanks for the reply, please see the updated post which contains more details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `np.indices`:

```
In [199]: idx = np.indices((2,2,2))

In [200]: idx.shape
Out[200]: (3, 2, 2, 2)

In [201]: idx
Out[201]: 
array([[[[0, 0],
         [0, 0]],

        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [1, 1]],

        [[0, 0],
         [1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 1],
         [0, 1]],

        [[0, 1],
         [0, 1]]]])
```

That's like your `A` but with an added size 3 dimension.

```
In [202]: idx[:,:,:,1]
Out[202]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]])
```

Which can be turned into your desired array with:

```
In [203]: idx[:,:,:,1].reshape(3,4).T
Out[203]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, data, time=None):
        obj = np.asarray(data).view(cls)
        obj.time = time
        return obj
    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        setattr(self, 'time', obj.time)
        try:
            self.time = self.time[obj._new_time_index]
        except:
            pass

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            if isinstance(item, (slice, int)):
                self._new_time_index = item
            else:
                self._new_time_index = item[0]
        except: 
            pass
        return super().__getitem__(item)
```